# read a file and remove characters using C

Tags: c, trim, readfile

I am struggling with read a file and remove some characters in the line, I can remove characters any how, but the char * contain so many unknown things.

this is inside of my file. just a one line

```
localpath=/home/ubu/myDocs
```

in my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

char *path;

int main()
{ 
  static const char filename[] = "pathFile";
  FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );

   if ( file != NULL )
   {
      char line[512];
      while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) // read a line 
      {
         fputs ( line, stdout ); // write the line 
         path = strchr(line,'=') +1 ;
      }
      fclose ( file );
   }
   else
   {
      perror ( filename ); // why didn't the file open? 
   }
}
```

but the problem is I can't use path, as example chdir(path); is not working,
but if I use like this strcpy(path,"/home/ubu/myDocs"); I can use it,

So get am idea I print the char like this

for (i=0, i < 200; i++)
printf(path[i]);

in the first case I got some weird character after the("/home/ubu/myDocs") in output, but in the second case I didn't get that kind of things and it works well. I can't understand what to do, I followed so many methods in internet, but same thing happen, Please  explain me what happen and give me some solution

p.s
I found that in first case chdir return value is < 0, that mean path is wrong no,,,but it consists path and something useless thing

thanks

Comment: I see no usage of `path` anywhere in this code besides the assignment, but if it is after the if-block where line[] is declared your line[] array would be out of scope. If you need it anywhere past the if-block you should consider setting up another char buffer[] and copying it out. Once line[] is gone (and it is as soon as you leave your if-block) the behavior to access its memory is undefined.

Comment: I am using path in other methods, like chdir(path); thats why I declared it as a global variable. but in second case it works well, what I want to insted of hard code "home/ubu" in code , read it from a file

Comment: yeah, I doubled check, chdir return < 0 value

Comment: The path *pointer* variable may be global, but the memory it is pointing *to* most certainly is not. it is in the line[] buffer declared in the local scope of your if-block. if all usage of *path is within the confines of the if-block (including call-outs to other functions) it can work, otherwise you need a global *buffer*, not just a global pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add exactly what output you see from your `printf()`?

My best guess is that `fgets()` is just including extra characters. When you do an `fgets()` and you pass in `sizeof line` it will read up to 512 characters but will stop after a newline, `\n`, or EOF (or perhaps other characters like a carriage return, `\r`). In particular, if there's a newline in your file, that will get copied over in the `fgets()`. Try removing any extra characters at the end of the path in your file.

**Edit** So you have two separate problems. First is why you see garbage when you print the `path`. Well... that's because you print 200 characters. What do you want the other ~190 characters to be? I do not know why you don't see garbage when you use `strcpy()` but you haven't really shown exactly what you did. The second problem is the one that @WhozCraig pointed out. Your `line` goes out of scope at the end of that `if` block. If you call `chdir()` on path after that point then `path` points to garbage.

Comment: yeah, I also think fgets put extra things, but how to avoid that,,,out put contain "/home/ubu/myDocs" and some unicode characters like boxes, question marks, and please consider chdir give me < 0 value,,,that mean path is not correct no?

Comment: Well one reason why you might be getting those extra characters is because you print 200 characters in your loop... I'm not exactly sure why you don't get garbage when you use `strcpy()`. You should probably just do a `printf(%s)` if you want to see the string, or if you want to print each character individually:
`for (...) { if (path[i] != '\0') printf("%c", path[i]); }`

Comment: thanks for your cooperation, problem is size of line. if I take exact size, the error will not occur.